# JSFiddle form not working

Tags: javascript, forms, jsfiddle

please help me with this

**Here's my JSfiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=kdFuCUrgmB

I have form with five inputs and javascript which check what user input into it.

It must return error if input field "ime" have less than 3 characters. 
It must return error if input field "prezime" OR "drzava" is empty and it must have at least 3 characters.
It must return error if input field "lozinka" and "potvrda-lozinke" are empty. That two fields must match and have at least 4 characters and at most 10 characters.

If anything is wrong with form it must return "Imate gresku, provjerite formu!" in div greska and create red border on fields that are wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jsFiddle options (Left side of screen) choose:Frameworks & Extensions and "No Wrap - in Head" instead of "onLoad".